varying response time for the loadtest of same count of users
I recently ran load tests for an API that utilizes caching, and I’m experiencing significant differences in response times between runs. Here are the details:
Load Test Setup:
Number of users: 22,000
The first test run had a maximum response time of 1.2 seconds.
The second test run, without changing any parameters, had a maximum response time of 5 seconds.
AWS Metrics:
During the second run, I noticed a spike in CPU usage with a maximum of 200% and an average of around 80%.
Other Relevant Info:
The API has a caching feature, which might be affecting the performance.
I’m trying to understand why the response time increased so drastically between the two runs, especially given the same setup and similar user loads.
My Question:
What could be causing such a large difference in response time between the two test runs?
How can I pinpoint the exact reason for this?
Are there specific areas (e.g., caching, CPU spikes, resource exhaustion) that I should be investigating further?

"Number of users: 22,000 " - this is very interesting but

what is your ramp-up period
what is your test duration
are any other components used like Timers

in other words are you sure you're running the same test 2 times or it might be the case workload model is different?
If you're absolutely sure that you're running the same test 2 times and system under test is "fresh" (i.e. restarted, caches are warmed up, test data is the same, etc.) and still getting different response times you can use profiler or APM tool to check what's going on under the hood and what exactly causes increased response times in 2nd case.
